# Remove a line with condition

Tags: regex, sed

```
ALTER TABLE variable ADD KEY somekey name
```

I want to remove the line from a text file and the sed mentioned below is working as expected.

```
sed '/ADD\ KEY/d'
```

But it's possible that the word "ADD KEY" may be somewhere else in the text file and I do not want to remove that line.

How do I remove all the "ADD KEY" lines only if it starts with "ALTER TABLE" word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 sed '/ALTER TABLE .* ADD KEY .*/d' FILE
```

should do the job as well. You don't need to mask a blank, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

do:

```
sed '/^ALTER TABLE/{/ADD\ KEY/d}'
```

The first `/^ALTER TABLE/` checks for lines starting with ALTER TABLE, and then proceeds with the `/ADD\ KEY/d` if that's true.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the regular expression to match the line starting as you need, i.e:

```
sed '/^ALTER\ TABLE.*ADD\ KEY/d'
```

which is
- line starting with "ALTER TABLE"
- followed by 0 or more 'anything'
- followed by "ADD KEY"